# regex using OR in statement

Tags: regex, ant, replace, wildcard

I am using Ant and I want to match strings that look like `import package.R;` and `import package.R.*;` but not `import package.Rxxx;`

so it is very specific that I only want to some kind of wild card for these two characters `;` and `.`

My current solution uses two different statements

`match="import.+?\.R;"`

`match="import.+?\.R."`

but I would like to combine them into one, for speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know much about ant specific regex but if it supports character classes as it should, then

```
match="import.+?\.R[;.]"
```

Should work `[;.]` meaning `;` or `.`

Comment: okay, this did as you intended, but my replacement statement works against me. With strings ending in `R;` I want to keep that part as is, so my replacement statement uses the `;`, but for strings ending in `R.*` I want to keep them as is too, so my replacement statement can't use the `;`... sorry if this is vague but I need a statement for this condition too. This is my current replace `replace="import ${current.target}.R;"`

Comment: You mean you dont want the final `;` on lines that end with `.*`?  `match="import.+?\.R(;|\.\*)"` `replace="import ${current.target}.R\1"`

Comment: @didster for what it's worth, Ant just uses Java for regexp.  There isn't an "Ant specific regex" syntax.

Comment: @Jeanne Boyarsky Thanks - in that case "I dont know much about Java specific regex" either ;o) - all of my RegEx is really from Perl.